# How do I print information from a text file between two points?

Tags: python

I am working on a project and am having trouble.
Keep in mind i am a beginner programmer.

What I want to do is print the information that is in the text file, between two points.

My Code:

```
AccountName=input("What Is The Name Of The Account Holder?")

Accounts=open("Accounts.txt", "r")
lines = Accounts.readlines()
Accounts.close

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if AccountName in line:
        print(line)
```

Text File:

`Alex Peters
Aken
South Carolina
Citizens Bank
865074
$25,000
09/25/2013
12401
(845)545-5555
Joe Small
Albany
New York
Key Bank
763081
$4,800
10/15/2013
24503
(845)734-5555`

Say I want to print from "Joe Small" to (845)734-5555
How would i do that?

(None Of this Information is real)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the line in question, and you have used `.readlines`, then you could find the sublist required with:

```
sublines = lines[lines.index('Joe Small'):lines.index('(845)734-5555')+1]
```

You could then print each line in that list.

Note, however, that this approach won't work if there are multiple unique lines in the list.

I would take an approach more like:

```
startLine = 'Joe Small'
endLine = '(845)734-5555'

shouldPrint = False

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if shouldPrint:
        print line

    if line == startLine:
        shouldPrint = True
    elif line == endLine:
        shouldPrint = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the for loop as (in Python3)

```
line_index = 0
while line_index < len(lines):
    if AccountName in lines[line_index]:
        for line in lines[line_index:line_index+9]:
            print(line, end="")
        line_index += 9
    else:
        line_index += 1
```

In Python 2.X, the print sentence should be :

```
print line,
```

Comment: Thank You @Sheng Your answer helped me get the end result i was looking for!

Comment: @johnthexiii It happens sometimes, the asker get the answer, leave away, and never upvote or accept any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like sapi's solution,

```
Accounts=open("file.txt", "r")
lines = Accounts.readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
Accounts.close()

accounts = zip(*[iter(lines)]*9)

for account in accounts:
    if "Joe Small" in account:
        print account
```